# What is the perfect Squat depth and tempo?

Tags: squats, legs, calisthenics, boxing, plyometrics

I have been lifting for 3 years managed a 170kg/375lbs squat with belt and low bar. Now I wish to start over with my squat and perform it high bar. My question is what is the best depth for the squat (parallel/ATG) and what is the best tempo (3-0-1/1-1-1) for best performance, power and muscle engagement.

Thanks!

Update: Thank you E.Aigle for your input on the original inquiry. As an update my specific goal for training now is for boxing and doing so in my own way. I would appreciate all inputs from anyone with something to say.

** Please read the comments **

Comment: Is this for the purpose of a specific sport, health or aesthetics? Olympic lifting for example requires pretty deep squats and a fast concentric phase most of the time. Depth and tempo are gonna depend on the end goal.

Comment: Agreed with E.Aigle here, there is no *perfect* squat tempo. They'll be goal-specific and even then you can use multiple. Are you powerlifting, general lifting, Olympic lifting?

Comment: My goal would be to not focus on the 1RM as much now, instead focus on building muscle and explosiveness (e.g. coming out of the bottom phase) while maintaining correct form and hitting optimal depth. I plan to use barbell squat as my primary leg compound for leg days to increase my overall performance and allow it to carry over to sports.

Comment: If you don't have a specific goal (like a competition of some sort) coming up, I'd recommend mixing it up to keep from getting bored and reduced risk of over use injury. The "best" tempo and depth depends entirely on what you're going to do, and if you're not doing anything specific, the answer can't really be anything specific either. Try paused squats to work on getting out of the bottom, or full ROM squats with a bounce in the bottom.

Comment: E.Aigle I appreciate your comment. I will for sure utilize paused squats as you've recommended. I am already doing the full ROM squats atm and it's been awesome lowering the weight tons to a achieve clean controlled form. I like your idea of mixing it up! Thank you.

Comment: If I can add on to your point on my specific goal, it would be boxing. This sport requires immense endurance in the muscles and personally I wish to build on my explosiveness atm so I can also implement high reps bodyweight leg movements and plyometrics after I have reaped a sufficent amount of gains from the weights. Hopefully this can give a clear indication to why I chose form, reps & explosiveness over a one rep max single due to my specific goal.

Comment: E.Aigle I'm curious to hear your opinion. I'm thinking out loud right now with that It might be ideal for me to eventually compile my workout regime consisting of weights, calisthenics and plyometric in harmony for my goal. What do you think?

Comment: @Sikandar maybe you can ask another question or edit this question and the tags to get more expert opinions on this subject